# Can chain index be configured to sync from a particular slot?

Tags: chain-index

The chain-index syncs from genesis all over again, everytime there is a version change or sometimes even for other reasons. Can it be set to sync only from a particular slot to save on the time spent for syncing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it currently cannot. Maybe some time in the future.